# Jasperreport Excel file creation exception

Tags: java, excel, exception, netbeans, jasper-reports

Im getting error while creating .xls file in the jasper reports.
**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet.addMergedRegion(Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/util/CellRangeAddress;)I
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.createMergeRegion(JRXlsExporter.java:596)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.initCreateCell(JRXlsExporter.java:540)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.createTextCell(JRXlsExporter.java:530)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.exportText(JRXlsExporter.java:390)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportPage(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:550)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:423)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:207)
at net.sf.jasperreports.view.save.JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.save(JRSingleSheetXlsSaveContributor.java:112)
at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer.btnSaveActionPerformed(JRViewer.java:1128)
at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JRViewer$3.actionPerformed(JRViewer.java:668)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at
```

**Code**

```
File reportFile = new File("C:/Documents and Settings...../report1.jrxml");
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFile);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, conn);
JasperViewer jv = new JasperViewer(jasperPrint);
```

But i can able to generate other type of report file.In this excell file is getting generated but the data is not in the file.Im using **jasperreports.jar** file.It's due to the deprecation i think.How can i solve this?

Comment: Which version of jasper reports are you using?

Comment: im using **jasperreports.jar**.Its 1.x.x

Comment: @sakthibalaji This is very old version. May be you should upgrade it? You should check the `poi` library dependency. You are using wrong version of this library

Comment: i rr replieseplaced it with 3.7.4....its working now ....Thanks for you